# Change command-line prompt leading character?

Tags: command-line

[image]

Reason: 
I've swapped my semi-colon and colon commands so that entering the command-line takes one less key-stroke:

```
nnoremap ; :
nnoremap : ;
vnoremap ; :
vnoremap : ;
nnoremap q; q:
```

But in the command-line prompt, the colon character still shows up. I would like this character to be a semi-colon instead so my brain doesn't have to deal with cognitive dissonance.

Comment: You can't. Life's too short to worry about such things anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no configuration option that does this; change the ':' into ';' you need to change the vim source code (which lives on github).

The relevant line (as of the most recent commit on github) is found [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/70bcd7336f9f19304f32c52a86ed5b4b3de852c2/src/ex_docmd.c#L1011).

You need to change `fgetline(':', cookie,` into `fgetline(';', cookie,`.
(Other characters that do not clash with existing characters used for the command line such as `=`, `/`, `?` should work as well, but I am not familiar enough with the source code to be sure.)

(*Personal interjection*: In general, this procedure is fragile and expose your vim installation to bugs. I wouldn't recommend it.)